# 2D Floor Plan not loading correctly in Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk

I am using Autodesk Forge to display 3D model and floor plans of a building in a web application. I am using `rac_advanced_sample_project.rvt` sample model I found on Autodesk Knowledge network sample revit projects.

I was able to display both 3D and floor plans in my web application, but now I can't  load the Floor plans (3D model is working fine). I am getting black, blue and white spots on loading floor plans.

[image]

And I am also attaching image for console error.

[image]

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the section named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Could you share the way and code snippets demonstrating how you load the model? The snapshots you provided is not enough for me to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with viewer version(6.2). For 2D Floor plans, it was displaying that view. I changed the version of viewer to 6.3 and it worked fine.

Comment: Nic, it's great to hear this issue has resolved. A suggestion for viewer base app is to reference viewer libraries with minor and patch versions. For example, `v6.3.*` 
 Please see here for the details: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/versioning-your-viewer-based-app